# Electric (120),only getting 70 volts,after breaker box

Tags: electrical

From pole to breaker box got 120 and 112,112 changes to only 70 volts,what causes this problem?

Comment: Does the other leg/side of the service go *up* in voltage when the one leg reads 70V?

Comment: No,it stays the same

Comment: Are you reading this with a digital voltmeter?  If you plug a small load like a night-light into the circuit at your test point, does the reading change to near zero?

Comment: Yes, lots of people get fooled by digital multi meters.  An unloaded circuit near other active circuits can have induced current (like a transformer).  Like Harper said, put a small load on the circuit and then take a voltage reading.  I was working in an older commercial building one time and kept getting shocked by a circuit that was turned off.  The wiring was in conduit with other active circuits.  Volt meter reading was 170v.   I put an incandescent lamp across the circuit to be sure and it dropped to almost zero.   Had to put on rubber gloves to complete my work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an open neutral and is a dangerous situation. Call the power company and report the trouble. They will check their facilities and your meter can for problems. If the problem is in your breaker panel, they might be able to fix it or they will tell you to call an electrician. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, will a bad connection cause that problem too?

Comment: @JamesASirak An "open neutral" *is* a bad connection; the worst kind.